# Creating drop-down search menu box

Tags: python, drop-down-menu

I have a list of Items and its price. What I want to do is that create a text box with drop-down list that gets updated every-time I add a character. When the item is selected, its price should appear in the next textbox. Which programming language should I use? Note: I am quite familiar with python.

Comment: I do not have experience, but python is easy enough if you want to give it a try. Also, if you want, I could provide you with an application that has a GUI that I built using tkinter. It might not be good for a corporation environment, but you could learn from it, I suppose(provided you re not experienced with GUI s)